# Terminate and get results from an event bus

Tags: java, rx-java, vert.x

Let's say I've got two verticles that are discovering special file names (for example. could be anything though) and publishing them to **event bus** e.g. one is reading names from a REST api and another from a filesystem:

*ScanRestVerticle.java*

```
/**
 * Reads file names through an REST API
 */
public class ScanRestVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        HttpClientRequest req = vertx.createHttpClient().request(HttpMethod.GET, "BASE_URL", "URL");

        req.toObservable()
           .flatMap(HttpClientResponse::toObservable)
           .lift(unmarshaller(Model.class))
           .subscribe(c -> vertx.eventBus().publish("address", c.specialName()));
        req.exceptionHandler(Throwable::printStackTrace);
        req.end();
    }
}
```

*ScanFsVerticle.java*

```
/**
 * Reads file names from a file
 */
public class ScanFsVerticle.java extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        StringObservable.byLine(vertx.fileSystem()
            .rxReadFile("myFileNames.txt")
            .map(Buffer::toString)
            .toObservable())
            .subscribe(c -> vertx.eventBus().publish("address", c), e -> System.err.println(e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Everything works great here, but, now, I have an verticle which is combining these names from an event bus and print them on STD.OUT:

*PrintVerticle.java*

```
public class PrintVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        vertx.eventBus()
            .<JsonObject>consumer("address")
            .bodyStream()
            .toObservable()
            .reduce(new JsonArray(), JsonArray::add)
            .subscribe(j -> System.out.println(j.toString()));
}
```

The problem is that **reduce** here is never actually completed, because event bus is making an infinite stream as I think.

So how do I actually complete this operation and print the names published by both verticles?

*Note:* I'm really new in vert.x and rx and I might missing some pieces or get something wrong, so please dont' judge :)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I could call `scan()` instead of `reduce()` here, to get intermediate results, but how would I get `scan().last()`?

Comment: what is your definition for completion? if you want to collect every 2 names published by 2 sources, then you need to distinguish between the 2 events

Comment: Thanks for question! As you can see in example, I want collect all names from both "scan" verticles and join them in the "print" verticle... of course this is simplified example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming correctly, `reduce()` operator relies on `onComplete()` event to know where to stop to collect.
while `scan()` is accumulator that emit accumulated value for each new emission of source stream, so scan will give you intermediate results.
The issue here is, that your'e using an `EventBus`, Conceptually, `EventBus` is infinite stream, so `onComplete()` should never be called. technically it might be called when you `close()` the `EventBus, but I guess yo shouldn't and don't want to rely upon it.

- If you do want to use an EventBus, you should somehow end your `PrintVerticle` stream, so you'll have `onComplete()` event. for instance, You can use the `EventBus` to publish some events that publishes each of the 2 observed vertices end. then you can zip it and end your stream (using `takeUntil()`) at `PrintVerticle` after this 2 events emitted.
  Something like this:

  ```
  Observable vertice1EndStream = vertx.eventBus()
      .<JsonObject>consumer("vertice1_end")
      .bodyStream()
      .toObservable();

  Observable vertice2EndStream = vertx.eventBus()
      .<JsonObject>consumer("vertice2_end")
      .bodyStream()
      .toObservable()

  Observable bothVerticesEndStream = Observable.zip(vertice1EndStream, vertice2EndStream, (vertice1, vertice1) -> new Object());

  vertx.eventBus()
      .<JsonObject>consumer("address")
      .bodyStream()
      .toObservable()
      .takeUntil(bothVerticesEndStream)
      .reduce(new JsonArray(), JsonArray::add)
      .subscribe(j -> System.out.println(j.toString()));
  ```
- Another option, is to use directly the 2 streams instead of the `EventBus`. merge them together and then use `reduce()`, as those 2 streams are finite ones, you will not have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for an suggestions... I thought I'll go with `EventBus`, but using only `Observables` is actually simpler and I feel it's somehow more "pure".